# Checking UIButton state for if condition

Tags: swift, uibutton

How can I check my button control state. I want to stop AVAudioplayer when the button is released.

Comment: There are many control events to choose from, pick some -- UIControlEvents.TouchDown
UIControlEvents.TouchDragOutside
UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken you could use Control event TouchDown for press and TouchUpInside for release. Take a closer look at control events and implement the two methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add a target and a selector for a specified event. Typically that message gets sent to the view controller as follows:

`button.addTarget(self, action: "someSelector", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`

You will need to implement the method `someSelector` in `self`, which is normally the containing view controller.

You can also do this in storyboard by creating an `IBAction` on your `UIButton`. When in the Assistant Editor, your storyboard or xib on one side, the view controller on the other, Ctrl+Click the button and drag over to the place you want to put the `IBAction` in your view controller.

Comment: How can I do this with the interface builder created one?

Comment: @arshiyaasd Updated answer

Comment: How ca I use the events though

Comment: TouchUpInside, as used in my example, means when the tap originates and finished inside the buttons bounds.

Comment: You can listen for many other envoys listed here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I want to stop avaudioplayer after releasing the button